# Route in Angular 2 two pages from one

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a component called hello and I want it to route to the register and login components based on the user input.
So if home.component.html has a login button and I click it it will go to login.component.html and the same for register

Right now it just loading a blank page with no errors.

**Update**
I have changed the hello.component.html to include the Login and Register but can only use one of them:

**hello.component.html same as app.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <register-cmp></register-cmp>
  <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
    <a [routerLink]="['/register']"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <login-cmp>Login</login-cmp>
  <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="main-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

**hello.routes.ts**

```
export const HelloRoutes: Route[] = [
{
    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloComponent,
    children: [
        ...LoginRoutes,
        ...RegisterRoutes
    ]
}];
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
...HelloRoutes,
...DashboardRoutes,
{
  path: '**',
component: HelloComponent
},];
```

[image: Project Structure]

The thing is I have the same setup with dashboard who links to users and home but I can't get it to work with home->(login/register)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to navigate to two components at once. You should navigate to a container that loads the two sub-components.

Comment: I would like to make home.component an html page that if you click login it redirects to login and the same for register